# Possible to use output of one command as an argument for an alias?

Tags: unix, command-line

I have zshell, and an alias for [sublime text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/)

I often look at the source of bundled gems, so I'll run this

```
bundle show gemname
```

-> outputs the path which I have to copy

```
subl path/to/gem
```

I want to pass the output of the first command into the alias as it's argument.

Is something like this possible with aliases:

```
bundle show gemname | subl
```

Or some variation thereof?

I'm not very familiar with the full suite of unix command line capability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that this should do exactly what you want:

```
subl `bundle show gemname`
```

Note the backtick characters, which is usually the key to the left of the 1 key and also below the esc key on a typical keyboard. This says to run the command in the backticks and use it's output in the outer command.